# Website javascript faulty when collapsing on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you click this link to follow the website

Pay close attention to how the header slider loads.

If you noticed, it collapses after the 100% loading div, before expanding with the images. The images and slides consist of background-images and CSS gradiets.

In the JS script, it sets the header div into an auto height, but I'm not familiar with how to set a set height after the loading div, to prevent the collapse.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `min-height` in CSS to the element that's equal to the height of the div while it's loading images.  You shouldn't need to mess with the JS.

This way, it'll only expand the height of the element, not collapse and then expand.